# Any way to prevent a notification from appearing in Notification Center?

Tags: notifications

I'm writing a simple AppleScript to create periodic notifications, but I don't want those notifications to accumulate in Notification Center. Is there any way to keep them from appearing there, or to expire them, or to delete them?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the notification centre
2. Press the little cog icon on the bottom right
3. Find your application in the list
4. Select your application and unselect "Show in notification center".

Comment: Yes, thanks. I was looking for a way to do programmatically, though that could work if it's the only option.